# Clockworkmod USB tethering with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, android, tethering

I have successfully installed and used Clockworkmod USB tethering for several years with Ubuntu 16.04.  After an upgrade to 18.04 I followed the same procedure as previously used with 16.04 (see [youtube video with instructions in the description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhYcc2EEZ-Y)), but with 18.04 the installation stops when I reach the "configure" stage.

Specifically,

> in Terminal and in the "node" folder (or directory) simply type:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> ```

this produces:

```
File "./configure", line 463, in 
    configure_node(output)
File "./configure", line 370, in configure_node
    o['variables']['gcc_version'] = 10 * cc_version[0] + cc_version[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Has anyone successfully gotten around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used CWM Tether myself, but I've just read over the script to see where the error is coming from.

The problem seems to be that `gcc` version 7+ only prints the major version number when run with `-dumpversion`. So it seems like you just need to go to line 325 in the script:

```
  proc = subprocess.Popen(CC.split() + ['-dumpversion'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and change `['-dumpversion']` to `['-dumpfullversion']`.

For best compatibility, the devs may want to switch it to `['-dumpversion', '-dumpfullversion']`.

And then hopefully there are no other incompatibilities.

Source: [gcc 7.1.1 on Fedora 26 dumpversion now only includes major version by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168516/gcc-7-1-1-on-fedora-26-dumpversion-now-only-includes-major-version-by-default)

And FWIW, other people are having the same issue [on 18.04](https://github.com/koush/support-wiki/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20cc_version) and [17.10](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376021).

Comment: Thank you -- the change in the script to '-dumpfullversion' solved the error, BUT then , MAKE produces:

Comment: ..included from ../deps/v8/src/elements.h:32:0,
 ../deps/v8/src/objects.h:7152:36: error: left operand of shift expression ‘(-8 << 26)’ is negative [-fpermissive]
deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8_base.target.mk:211: recipe for target '/home/elickm/Downloads/tether/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/elickm/Downloads/tether/Tether/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/elickm/Downloads/tether/Tether/node/out'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2

Comment: @drboy Please edit your question to add that info. Unfortunately I don't know how to troubleshoot make files.

Comment: here is the make file:

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to respond properly.  if however, you go back to the video or to clockworkmod.com, the tether-linux.tgz from CWM you will find the node folder in the Tether folder and therein you will find the "makefile" script.

Comment: Fixed it for me, debian 10.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This fixed the ./configure, but it apparently didn't successful compile (after running it twice it looks like it failed). I'll look for another app.